# VS2010 for Office Development

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, officedev

I have Visual Studio 2010 Professional however it seems as though I cannot open/create Office Projects.

I assumed there must have been something wrong with my install and a feature wasn't added. However whenever I go into my Maintenance Mode for my VS2010 nothing about Office appears. And it does say Professional, which I believe comes with office tools.

I do have Office 2010 also installed.

I've looked around and everywhere says that I can just add that feature, but I only get a number of features in my install; VB, C++. C# (plus X64 Compilers and Tools), Visual Web Developer and Graphics Library, all of which are tickets.

Any tips?

p.s. I do also have SP1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else that may encounter this problem, you may need to reinstall SP1 as well as Visual Studio. This is what did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

[**VSTO**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh133430.aspx) is what you're looking for.

Try one of the [walkthrough articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff937654) to get started.